# c# script compilation vscode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, compilation

I tried running simple code in my vscode. initially got of "scripts not found internally or externally" after installing the scripts from "choclately" and installing "sriptcsRunner" extension.
I'm again facing a problem running my code.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to [so], please if possible add the code and the error you get as text to your question, not as image.

Comment: `scriptcs` is not a compiler but a way to run c# scripts. If that's what you want, reduce it down to `using System; Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");` and it should work. If not, then you want [csc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe), not scriptcs

Answer (score 0):

For VisualStudio Code all you really need to run is the C# extension.

To create a new project you open the integrated terminal in VS Code inside your workspace and run

```
dotnet new console
```

That will create everything you need.

You might need to run `.NET Generate Assets for Build and Debug`, you can do so by pressing `ctrl + shift + P` and enter the above command there, it should pretty much autocomplete.

to debug your program you can run by pressing `F5`

To execute normally use this:

```
dotnet run
```